template template concepts to allow concepts to be templated on other concepts?
In C++20, is it possible for a concept to be templated on another concept?
I can do
template <typename R>
concept RangeOfFloats = std::ranges::range<R> && std::floating_point<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>;

static_assert(RangeOfFloats<std::span<float>>);
static_assert(RangeOfFloats<std::span<double>>);

to define a concept that a range has floats in it.
I can do
template <typename R, typename T>
concept RangeOfType = std::ranges::range<R> && std::is_same_v<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, T>;

static_assert(RangeOfType<std::span<float>, float>);
static_assert(!RangeOfType<std::span<float>, double>);

to explicitly constrain a range of an exact type.
But I can't see a way to put those ideas together. I'd expect syntax like this to work:
template <typename R, template <typename> concept ElementConstraint>
concept RangeOfThingsLike = std::ranges::range<R> && ElementConstraint<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>;

static_assert(RangeOfThingsLike<std::span<float>, std::floating_point>);

but it doesn't.
I can use type traits, replacing concept with typename, but yuck!:
template <typename R, template <typename> typename ElementConstraint>
concept RangeOfThingsLike = std::ranges::range<R> && ElementConstraint<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>::value;

static_assert(RangeOfThingsLike<std::span<float>, std::is_floating_point>);

I tried template <typename> bool ElementConstraint and template <typename> auto ElementConstraint, passing std::is_floating_point_v, but only class and typename are allowed there after template <typename>.
Is there a way to pass a concept to a template?
https://godbolt.org/z/xnf9E14qE
